# jstl validates c:if on timeout which cause exception

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl

i have a page that use RichFaces and jsf , i added some jstl code to validate something in the bean, well this code is being validated when the session timeouts, and this triggers some exception, the code is :

```
<c:if test="#{ViewerController.viewerBean.canCountMessages}" >
    <td>
        <a4j:commandButton value="count" action="#{ViewerController.doCount}" />
    </td>
</c:if>
```

so this code gets validated and the following exception is thrown:

```
/pages/viewer/index.xhtml @43,67 test="#{ViewerController.viewerBean.canCountMessages}" An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean ViewerController
```

is there a way to prevent the c:if tag to be validated when the session is not valid

note: the ViewerController class is SessionScoped .

Comment: The terminology in your question is very confusing. This exception is not caused by some validation error on the code. It's just caused by a bug in your own code. Please look for the root cause in the stack trace to learn about the root cause of the exception. Plus, the `[jsp]` tag on your question is also confusing as you don't seem to be using JSP at all.

Comment: it is my mistake not to say it clearer, well what i was asking for is that when the session gets invalid by the timeout why the c:if test statement gets validated and executed, the calling of ViewerController.viewerBean.canCountMessages crash due to some - maybe session dependent - code that gets called and it might test on some object stored in the session itself, what i was asking for is that can i do something like <c:if test="#{ isSessionValid and ViewerController.viewerBean.canCountMessages}" >, that might fix this.

Comment: No, your problem is caused by a problem in resource injection in the bean, exactly as the top exception message says. Just look in the stack trace for the root cause of this problem. E.g. a `NullPointerException` or so. Then just fix the code accordingly based on that information.

Comment: the thing is that i was able to know what the root cause of the error, its that in somewhere in the initialization of the ViewerController managed bean i was querying some variable saved in the session and was assuming that it does exist, but while the timeout occurred why does it try to re-validate the page again, i am using some Richfaces a4j tags and it does not evaluate the EL inside it, but yet the jstl c:if statement does , maybe that's the way it works and that's just it or maybe i have some configuration issues that i am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to get a workaround for this, it may help someone having a similar issue,

well, i have saved some variable in the session after user login, and the queried if this variable does exist in the c:if statement like :

when logging the user in the web app :

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("SessionValid",true);
```

and added this method in the ViewerController class:

```
boolean isSessionValid(){
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("SessionValid") !=  null ;
}
```

and my code is like :

```
<c:if test="#{ViewerController.sessionValid and ViewerController.viewerBean.canCountMessages}" >
    <td>
        <a4j:commandButton value="count" action="#{ViewerController.doCount}" />
    </td>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `if (sessionValid != null)` in the logic behind `canCountMessages` to prevent that you're invoking methods on `null`?

Comment: because i do initialize the bean (viewerBean) based on the data stored in the session it self ( using my ViewerDao ), so in the case of no session available, i didn't want to dig in this and i just didn't create the viewerBean ( null ) :)  , seems stupid but i am not that experienced in all this cause the first time i have ever seen jsp,jsf,richfaces.. is from 5 months ago, and i am a c++ developer ^_^

Comment: A NPE has nothing to do with JSP/JSF/RF, it's just part of basic Java. This is also indicated by the package name of the NPE class.